Incorrect reasoning when using law of total probability
I was trying to solve a problem from "Introduction to Probability" from course https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/. The problem statement is the following:
A bag contains one marble which is either green or blue, with equal probabilities. A green marble is put in the bag (so there are 2 marbles now), and then a random marble is taken out. The marble taken out is green. What is the probability that the remaining marble is also green?
My (incorrect) solution was: let $S$ be the event that the remaining marble is green. Let $T$ denote the event that we remove the second marble (i.e. the marble which is always green). We just need to find $P(S)$. Using law of total probability we get that:
$$P(S) = P(S \mid T)P(T) + P(S \mid T^c)P(T^c)$$
$P(S \mid T) = \frac{1}{2}$ since if we remove the second marble, then the first (remaining) marble is either green or blue with both equally likely,
$P(T) = \frac{1}{2}$ since randomly take 1 out of 2 marbles,
$P(S \mid T^c) = 1$ since if we remove first marble then second (remaining) marble has to be green,
$P(T^c) = \frac{1}{2}$ because $P(T) = P(T^c) = \frac{1}{2}$.
Plugging all those values in we get: $P(S) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.
According to the official solution (available here) the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$. Could somebody tell me which part of my solution was incorrect? I'm pretty sure it has to be something with definition of $T$ but I have no idea what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

$P(S,|,T)$ is not $\frac 12$ as you declare.  After all, that is what you are asked to compute.

@lulu No $P(S\mid T, G)=1/2$ because, when given that you removed the second marble and it is green, then the remaining marble is still equally as likely to be green as blue.  It is the probability that you extracted the second marble that is changed by the condition. $\mathsf P(T\mid G)=2/3$ because the fact that you extracted a green marble make it more likely that you had extracted the second marble.

@GrahamKemp  Absolutely, completely misread the notation.  Thanks.

Let A denote the case that the initial bag was green-green and B denote the case that the initial bag was green-blue.
Then...
$P(G|A) = 1$ and $P(G|B) = 1/2.$
We seek $P(A|G)$.
By Bayes formula:
$$P(A|G) = \frac{P(G|A) P(A)}{P(G|A)P(A) + P(G|B)P(B)} = \frac{1 \cdot 1/2}{1 \cdot 1/2 + 1/2 \cdot 1/2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Let's rephrase the question, so all probabilities are a little more intuitive to evaluate.
Start with two bags, one with a blue marble and one with a green marble.  Now add a green marble to each of them.  Shuffle the bags and fairly select one, then extract one marble.  Given that it is green, what is the probability that you selected the bag with two green marbles?
Well there are three green marbles that it could be, two of which are from the same bag, so the conditional probability is $2/3$.

You solution was in error because the the probability for selecting an added marble is not $1/2$ under the given condition that the extracted marble is green (call this event $G$).
As you had, $P(S\mid T, G)=1/2$ because, when given that you removed the second marble and it is green, then the remaining marble is still equally as likely to be green as blue.
However, $\mathsf P(T\mid G)=2/3$ because the fact that you extracted a green marble make it more likely that you had extracted the second marble.  (In the above restatement, two from the three green marbles had been added.)
By similar reasoning for the other case:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(S\mid G) &= \mathsf P(T\mid G)\,\mathsf P(S\mid T,G)+\mathsf P(T^\complement \mid G)\,\mathsf P(S\mid T^\complement, G)\\&=\dfrac 23\cdot\dfrac 12+\dfrac 13\cdot\dfrac 11\\&=\dfrac 23\end{align}$
